# How to insert and get data out of MSSQL with node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js

How can I get information out and put in information with *mssql* and *node.js*. A lot of tutorial taught differently and I want to learn using my code as I already learnt up till implementing the database for my express, *node.js*. Thanks for your help!

```
//Database
var myDatabase = require('./public/js/database')
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var SessionStore = require('express-session-sequelize')(expressSession.Store);
var sequelizeSessionStore = new SessionStore({
    db: myDatabase.sequelize,
});

//Database.js
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelizeTransforms = require('sequelize-transforms');

const sequelize =new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectModulePath: 'tedious',
    dialectOptions: {
      driver: 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
      instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS02'
    },
    host: 'localhost',
    username: 'shoppingCart',
    password: '12september2012',
    database: 'shoppingCart',
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        idle: 10000
      }
  });

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});

sequelizeTransforms(sequelize);

module.exports.sequelize = sequelize;
module.exports.Sequelize = Sequelize;
```

Comment: You need to configure first then connect to db.check this link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1238/connect-sql-server-nodejs-mssql-package

Comment: yea i configured